# parse qmake output from bash script

Tags: bash

How can I extract the Qt version from a bash script using 
`qmake -v`?

```
[newton@plex .home] qmake -v
Qmake version: 1.07a (Qt 3.3.6)
Qmake is free software from Trolltech AS.
[newton@plex .home]
```

### edit

sorry, i'm looking for 2.3.6

Comment: What specifically are you looking to get out of the result?

Comment: we can't hide anything from you Lukas :)

Comment: I was pointing out that Qt2 is ancient and now you changed it to 1.3.6. Are you really using that old version of Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
qmake -v | grep -m1 -o -P "\(Qt [^\)]+" | cut -d" " -f2
```

Comment: I get the accept same output as qmake -v am I missing something?

Comment: To test it, I substituted `qmake -v` with `echo "Qmake version: 1.07a (Qt 3.3.6)"` and it outputs `3.3.6` for me.